# ¿Existe alguna otra forma de hacer un Bubble Sort sin definirlo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

En Python3, cuando uno busca como hacer un bubble sort, encuentra algo así

```
def bubbleSort(alist):

    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]

bubbleSort(alist)

print(alist)
```

Me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de hacer el bubble sort sin tener que definirlo como una función, sin el "def bubbleSort(alist):"

Comment: Coloca el código del interior de la función después de la definición de la lista `alist` y reduce el nivel de identación para que `for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):` quede al mismo nivel que `alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]`, elimina la llamada a `bubbleSort` y ya está....

Comment: Si lo que estás preguntando (pues no se entiende claramente) es si Python ya implementa bubblesort para no tener que implementarlo tú, pues entonces que sepas que puedes ordenar la lista en una sola instrucción con `alist.sort()`, pero internamente no usa bubblesort, sino un algoritmo mucho más eficiente (timsort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es hacer un programa simple sin necesidad de definir una funcion, simplemente reemplaza la llamada a dicha funcion con el codigo de la misma.  Algo asi:

```
alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]

for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

print(alist)
```